# How to Mock Datasource in spring JdbcTemplate

Tags: unit-testing, junit, mockito, powermockito, spring-junit

Please help me to mock below code .Not able to mock getDataSource() which is calling upon JdbcTemplate object.

```
@Override
public List<AttributeThresholdRange> getThresholdsRangeForXHS(QueryThresholdsRequest queryThresholdsRequest) {

    ArrayOfString attributeGroupIds = queryThresholdsRequest.getAttributeGroupIds();
    Map<String, Object> queryParams = new HashMap<>();
    queryParams.put("groupids", attributeGroupIds.getStrings());

    return new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(admDatabaseConnector.getJdbcTemplate().getDataSource())
            .query(DBQueryConstants.ADM_QUERY_GET_THRESHOLDS_RANGE_FOR_XHS, 
                    queryParams,
                    new ResultSetExtractor<List<AttributeThresholdRange>>() {
                @Override
                public List<AttributeThresholdRange> extractData(ResultSet resultSet) throws SQLException,DataAccessException  {

                    return null;
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: is admDatabaseConnector autowrired?

Comment: also do you want to unit test it or integration test it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what´s the Mock framework are you using?

If you are using Mockito just Mock the `jdbcTemplate` and put this method in the `when()` clause.

```
when(admDatabaseConnector.getJdbcTemplate().getDataSource())
            .query(anyObject(), anyObject(), anyObject())).thenReturn("Your return queryobject");
```

You must declare the `admDatabaseConnector` in the Mock.

Comment: Thanks You .I used this logic and my Junit code is working fine.

Comment: @Gaurav  If this answer worked for you, you should accept the answer so that it's obvious